# Centralizing time-series data into a single micro-service for cross-entity querying

Tags: machine-learning, microservices

I'm developing a set of services using a microservice architecture pattern. Many of my models will have large amounts of time-series data which will be consumed by a machine learning engine.

I would like for my machine learning engine to be able to query for 'cross-entity' data. Meaning, that I would like to be able to compare the 'features' (machine learning term for data points / characteristic of an object being examined) across multiple objects.

It occurred to me that I could have a centralized microservice that is specifically designed to store and serve time-series information. If I could create an API between the service which stores my business objects and this feature service, then I could achieve this. With a single feature service (or perhaps one per domain model), I could poll any feature set from any model so long as the time resolution is the same.

**My question is:**

*Is a centralized time-series data store, in the form of a microservice which relates it's features to various models located in external services, a viable design pattern for achieving cross-entity feature querying? If not, what design patterns could be utilized for this purpose?*

I don't feel comfortable replicating time-series data storage, querying and manipulation in each and every microservice I create.

Here's a diagram showing the pattern I'm interested in developing:

[image: Centralized Feature Service]

Answer (score 1):

You can - it is called a database and it may very well be what you need. Microservices is a tool, not a goal

that said, if each microservice holds its own data where it is the "source of truth" and you need a copy of that data for reporting purposes (model building in your case) it is also a reasonable solution. I called this "[aggregated reporting](https://arnon.me/soa-patterns/aggregated-reporting/)"

Comment: So it's OK to have time-series features for many different entities stored in the same microservice?

Comment: There's almost no decision that is 100% wrong- it's all tradeoffs. time-series is usually immutable and generated independently - but even if all your services will be tied together to the same model it might be reasonable - what are the challenges you are trying to address?